# Header does not move to the left entirely when browser is small

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a menu. With my current implementation, the header content does not move to the left entirely when I make my browser small. How can I make css styles better so that it moves completely to the left when user makes his browser smaller.

My current code is below.

```
.header-container
  .header
    .logo
      %img{:src => 'assets/logo.png'}
    .menu
      %ul
        %li
          %a{:href => '#'} Home
        %li
          %a{:href => '#'} Features
        %li
          %a{:href => '#'} Pricing
        %li
          %a{:href => '#'} Team
        %li
          %a{:href => '#'} Support
```

Here is my scss

```
.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
background: url(menubg.jpg) no-repeat;

.header {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid red;

    img {
        float: left;
    }

    ul {
        border: 1px solid green;
        //min-width
        li {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin-right: 2%;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have u done a css reset?

Comment: I am using normalize.css

Comment: can you post a link to a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)?